# Consistently getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jvm-arguments

i am Consistently getting **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space Error** in Eclipse while opening any file in eclipse(exclipse gets closed and logs shows this error) and also when i manuaalu exit the exclipse it shows same error saying unable to save the state of workspace(stating permgen error) Here are the logs in log file under metadata foldet of workspace

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2011-12-14 10:42:09.464
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-12-14 10:42:11.336
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-12-14 10:42:12.303
!MESSAGE Shutdown error
!STACK 1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Even after I have changed the eclipse.ini parameters to  below values.Getting same error

```
-Xms4096m 
-Xmx4096m 
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 
4096m
```

**i am using eclipse helios 3.6 version and having RAM of 8 GB.
I am not getting how to get rid of this.**

Comment: 4G looks like an awefull lot of perm-space !!  you probably got a corrupted jar somewhere that is just enough ***ked up to cause trouble but not enough to crash altogether.  Download again and check MD5/SHA1 if you can to make sure you got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increase perm space by adding following line to eclipse.ini file

```
-XX:PermSize=XXXm -XX:MaxPermSize=XXXm
```

Comment: you mean like this -XX:PermSize=4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m. right?

Comment: Yes, JVM arguments detail are in following link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html hth

Comment: And you will never need more that 512MB of PermGen, and even this is a lot! Better give more Heap mem...

Answer (score 0):

If this issue occurs, just down a new distribution and reinstall..(i also faced some memory issue and i increased the memory but it didn't help me..)But re installation solved everything..

Answer (score 0):

I keep seeing this issue during the development of Eclipse plugin. The only way that I could get rid of it is to switch to a new workspace. My project source code is somewhere else, so every time I just need to import my project into the new workspace.

I believe there are something bad stored in the workspace, I just don't know what are they.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote code before this issue appears, just try to move your .log file or delete it. It is a issue because of the size from the log file.

Answer (score 0):

delete .metadata folder and restart eclipse and re-import all projects into your workspace. This worked for me.